# Why is Docker is incorrectly evaluating $HOME to "root"

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, docker

I'm running docker using command `docker build -t myimage:1.0 .` with the following lines included in the `Dockerfile`:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

But it incorrectly gives me error that I'm trying to access `/root/` even though I did not run as `sudo`. `$HOME` should have evaluated to my user, not root.

> `/bin/bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied`

What am I missing?

Comment: Docker uses root to install not a user. Make the path absolute.

Comment: @Rinzwind If I use the absolute path to my user's bashrc i get error `/bin/bash: /home/akiko/.bashrc: No such file or directory` even though the file really is my home's .bashrc